Case Subject in list view
In list view case subject is not showing as a full it basically getting ends with .... like this.
Case Subject : The Truman Show but it is showing something like below

I have tried using the wrap text that also not working also tried to expand the column but no luck any suggestion although under the case detail page on compact layout I am able to see full name.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion,

Just to update, It's a bug reported in new Winter release.
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000zgtTHAAY/~
